# installing now module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to install now module with command : `npm install now`
and it get me these three lines :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/now
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/now
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/now/-/now-0.8.1.tgz
```

and never changes or exits, I dont know is it normal or not.
any help is greate

Comment: Try running `npm install now --loglevel info`

Comment: i did,and it solved.but now it gives me the same error with node-proxy, and after i runned npm install node-proxy, it prints 5 lines, and stops, again , no exit , no message.what should I do?

Comment: How long did you wait? Perhaps the `now` module contains hundreds of megabytes of files?

Comment: is it possible? how long do I need to wait?

Comment: On my mac, it actually takes quite some time to run `npm install now`.  A lot of the dependencies contains C++ code that must be compiled.

Comment: What version of node / npm?

Comment: node 0.10.20   -   npm 1.3.11